# Snapchat message button in html

Tags: html, hyperlink, web, share, snapchat

I know if I click `href="snapchat://add/http://www.google.com"` it will open Snapchat application on the phone and let me add Google Snapchat account.

But what im asking is that I want to know how to send message or share a website link. If you share through android app like google chrome, I open options Press Share Choose snapchat and it allows me to select my friends and send. Thats the same thing i want to to with a website. (I am using a phone browser).

i tried a rough guess to replace the `add` in the link like

```
href="snapchat://send/http://www.google.com"

href="snapchat://share/http://www.google.com"

href="snapchat://text/http://www.google.com"
```

but nothing worked, Can anyone help ?

Comment: The thing to search for would be a Snapchat API because that is where you'd learn more about which links to use the company's functionality. However, as of February 2017, at least, Snapchat has not published a developer API and the company actively works to remove third party applications that access their API. Which means that any use of their links in the way you're describing is not approved by the company (and might be illegal? I'm not at all sure on this). Caveat emptor.

Comment: No API page. Well thank you for the answer. Is there a way to call android own Share intent throw HTML ? this way I can use it and according to it might not be illegal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your sentence: "Is there a way to call android own Share intent throw HTML ?" Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe such a thing exists. The closest is as you mentioned linking to a snapchat profile.